# New values not being loaded for .env for SvelteKit app

Tags: environment-variables, vite, svelte, sveltekit

I am unable to get Sveltekit to read the latest values from `.env`.

Any help on where are these old values coming from?

I have tried the following ways:

1.

```js
import { SALESFORCE_CLIENT_SECRET, SALESFORCE_CLIENT_ID, SALESFORCE_CALLBACK_URI_BASE } from '$env/static/private'
import { env } from '$env/dynamic/private'
console.log('meta.env.DEV-->', import.meta.env.DEV.valueOf());
console.log('settings-static-->', SALESFORCE_CALLBACK_URI_BASE)
console.log('settings-dynamic-->', env.SALESFORCE_CALLBACK_URI_BASE)
console.log('settings-process.env->', process.env.SALESFORCE_CALLBACK_URI_BASE)
```

They all show the "old value"

2. I entered `node` and explicitly set the `process.env.SALESFORCE_CALLBACK_URI_BASE` to a new value, but when I ran `npm run dev` this value was overwritten.
3. I explicitly installed `dotenv` package.
4. My `.env` file is at the base of the project and I also created a second `.env.local` with the correct values.
5. I restarted my VSCode.
6. In `svelte.config.js` I added `env` property.

```js
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
    kit: {
        env: {
            dir: '.',
        },
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};
```

7. Deleted `.svelte-kit/` and  `node_modules/.vite` and used `npm run dev`.

The above steps were done exclusive of each other and they did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the values were being persisted in my bash `env`.

You can print it by typing this in the terminal

```
env
```

From this [GH comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22429#issuecomment-1795856997) to "Show environment contributions" for my VSCode integrated zsh terminal, I checked that the `ms-python.python` VSCode extension had an
Activated environment for `~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/bin/python` which was bringing those values. (Maybe from an earlier project? I am not sure where they came from.)

so I used this [SO answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/91446) to unset those "old values".

```
unset SALESFORCE_CALLBACK_URI_BASE
```

After this svelte read my values correctly.
Still a bit weird why in a TS/JS project were python interpreter values being interfering.